# A Question about the difference of Two samples

Tags: probability, statistics

Problem:
From each of two normal populations with identical means and with standard
deviations of $6.40$ and $7.20$, independent random samples of $64$
observations are drawn. Find the probability that the difference between the
means of the samples exceeds $0.6$ in absolute value.

Answer:

Let ${\sigma_{s1}}^2$ be the sample variance for the first sample.
Let ${\sigma_{s2}}^2$ be the sample variance for the second sample.
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\sigma_{s1}}^2 &=& \frac{6.40}{64} = 0.1 \\
{\sigma_{s2}}^2 &=& \frac{7.2}{64} = 0.1125 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, let me define a new distribtuion called $s3$ and define it to be
the difference between the means of the two samples.  Let ${\sigma_{s3}}^2$ be
the sample variance for this new sample.
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\sigma_{s3}}^2 &=& {\sigma_{s1}}^2 + {\sigma_{s2}}^2 = 0.1 + 0.1125 \\
{\sigma_{s3}}^2 &=& 0.2125 \\
\sigma_{s3} &=& 0.40698 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
We need to convert the difference of $0.6$ into standard deviations. I do this
by computing $0.6 / \sigma_{s3}$. I find that $0.6$ converts to $2.8235$. The
z-score of $0.002375$. Now, that gives us the probability that it is
$0.6$ units above. It could also be $0.6$ units below. So the answer I seek
is $2(0.002375)$ or $0.00475$.
The book's answer is $0.617$. I am hoping that somebody can tell me where I
went wrong.

Thanks Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote:
${\sigma_{s1}}^2 = \frac{6.40}{64} = 0.1$

${\sigma_{s2}}^2 = \frac{7.2}{64} = 0.1125$

but I should have written:

${\sigma_{s1}}^2 = \frac{6.40^2}{64} = 0.64$

${\sigma_{s2}}^2 = \frac{7.2^2}{64} = 0.81$

When I propagate this change, I get an answer of 0.618 and the book gets
an answer of 0.617. I believe the difference is round off error. So, with this
change I consider my answer correct.

Bob

Answer (score 1):

"I do this by computing $0.6/\sigma_{s3}$. I find that $0.6$ converts to $2.8235$".  It looks to me like you divided $.6$ standard deviations by the variance.  Instead:
$$\frac{.6}{\sigma_{s3}} = \frac{.6}{.40698} \approx 1.474$$

Comment: You are right about that. However, with your correction I still get the wrong answer. The book's answer for the probability is 0.617. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Bob   I thought about it more and I can't reproduce the answer you are seeking.  I do see that you mistyped the standard deviation, it should be .46098, but that still doesn't give the probability in the book.